# Conventional headsep in academic proposal

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

In the pdf generated by the following code, from page 2, the first line overlaps with the header.

Does anyone know if there is any conventional measures for `headheight` and `headsep` on an A4 paper (for academic proposal)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[a4paper,
margin=15mm,
heightrounded,
headheight=0pt,
headsep=0pt,
includehead]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{layout}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Author}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[C]{Title}

\begin{document}

\layout

1 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

2 \lipsum*[1]

3 \lipsum*[1]

4 \lipsum*[1]

5 \lipsum*[1]%~\footnote{abc}

6 \lipsum*[1]

7 \lipsum*[1]

8 \lipsum*[1]

\pagestyle{fancy}
9 \lipsum*[1]

10 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

11 \lipsum*[1]

12 \lipsum*[1]

13 \lipsum*[1]~\footnote{abc}

14 \lipsum*[1]

15 \lipsum*[1]

16 \lipsum*[1]

17 \lipsum*[1]

18 \lipsum*[1]

19 \lipsum*[1]

20 \lipsum*[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The outcome on my machine is that of no header on the first page (with the layout and probably due to `\layout` using empty style) and then overlapping paragraphs and headers on all subsequent pages. Are you an using up-to-date LaTeX version?

Comment: The overlapping is expected because you have assigned `0pt` to both `headheight` and `headsep`. You would probably need something around these values: `headheight=11pt` and `headsep=3pt`.

Comment: what's your latex version?

Comment: The log: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.9)`. I tested your code on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/gwnfjzcktrns)

Comment: It happens only until TeX Live 2020. With TeX Live 2021 and later, the overlapping is on all pages from page 2 onwards.

Comment: In deed, I just upgraded Tex Live, we see overlapping on all the pages from page 2. I modified the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In TeXlive 2020, `fancyhdr` used to change `\headheight` when it detected it was too small. The change would be effected on the following pages. But this gave an inconsistent page layout, which is what you saw.

I changed this in `fancyhdr` version 4. So now you will get a consistent page layout, but if `\headheight` is too small you will get a warning on every page and you might get an overlap. So look into the log file and it will tell you the minimal value you need for `\headheight`.

```
Package fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): 
(fancyhdr)                Make it at least 13.59999pt, for example:
(fancyhdr)                \setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}.
(fancyhdr)                You might also make \topmargin smaller:
(fancyhdr)                \addtolength{\topmargin}{-13.59999pt}.
```

In your case you would need something like (rounded)

```
headheight=14pt,
```

I would advise not to change `headsep`. Just use the default value.